Battery percentage counter telling the wrong percentage when battery is full
My computer is an ASUS Vivobook Pro 16X OLED, a fairly new computer and I am using Ubuntu 22.04.4 with GNOME version 42.9 dual booting Windows 11. My problem is that when GNOME shows a battery percentage of around 94%, The battery indicator light -at the side of the computer- turns to white telling me that the battery is full. And then the battery percentage that GNOME shows slowly creeps up to 98% and then after some time it jumps to 100%.I am not bothered by this problem, but I am worried it will degrade my battery over time. am I right?

What makes you think the % is incorrect? I think this is just that the indicator light is white when the battery is full or nearly full. I don’t think your battery will experience excess wear. I’m still using an Asus Zenbook from circa 2012 that does this - battery’s not quite as good as when new, but still lasts about 6-8 hours.

@Will Thanks for your comment. as I have said before i have windows 11 and this problem doesn't happen
